# Stop axis from expanding matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been using the code from the site bellow to create and use check buttons for my subplot lines:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html

But i can't seem to keep the check button axes (rax) from expanding when i pull on the margins of the figure window, i would like only the plot with lines to expand. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to do the job:

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color='k', label='2 Hz')
l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color='r', label='4 Hz')
l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color='g', label='6 Hz')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

lines = [l0, l1, l2]

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
rax.autoscale(enable=FALSE, tight=TRUE)    #this is the part i don't want expanding
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)


def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way the do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: `autoscale` scales the axes units, not the position or extent of the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be translated into how to position an axes in figure coordinates with a fixed width and height in absolute (pixel) coordinates. This can be done via setting the axes locator to a
[`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.AnchoredSizeLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.AnchoredSizeLocator.html) via `ax.set_axes_locator`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import AnchoredSizeLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create axes, which is positionned in figure coordinates,
# with width and height fixed in inches.

# axes extent in figure coordinates (width & height ignored)
axes_extent = [0.03, 0.5, 0, 0]
# add axes to figure
rax = fig.add_axes(axes_extent)
# create locator: Position at (0.03, 0.5) in figure coordinates,
# 0.7 inches wide and tall, pinned at left center of bbox.
axes_locator = AnchoredSizeLocator(mtrans.Bbox.from_bounds(*axes_extent),
                                   .7, .7, loc="center left",
                                   bbox_transform=fig.transFigure,
                                   borderpad=0)
rax.set_axes_locator(axes_locator)
```

Now, when the figure size changes, the axes will stay at the same relative position without changing its width and height.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It looks a bit messy but it does the job

Comment: Yep, true, but it's not such a common requirement, so you need to use some more hidden functions.

Comment: I have another question: at this point in your answer, if i pull on the edges of the window that contains the graph and the buttons, the distance between the two is quite large. Is there a way to make the graph figure expand so it doesn't leave that much space between?

Comment: *"distance between the two"*  - the two *what*?

Comment: "ax" and "rax" - figure with the lines and figure with checkbuttons

Comment: I had the impression that was exactly what you wanted to achieve. If that's not what you want, using the code from the question without the fix from this answer seems to be better suited.

Comment: The answer is perfect because it keeps the checkbutton figure to a fixed size when i change the size of the window. I was wondering if there was a way to make the line figure more proportionate to the window when i expand it

Comment: It actually is completely proportionate to the window; setting `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)` the axes always starts at 20% from the left side.